# Ajax Enabled WCF with Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wcf

I have doubt whether we can pass params as data to ajax enabled WCF service using ajax call here is my script code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SendSms").click(function () {
                var data = 'Muthu';
                var text = JSON.stringify({ data: data });
                debugger;
                //data += '[0].Name=FromDate&[0].Value=' + 'Muthu';
                //data += '&[1].Name=ToDate&[1].Value=' + 'Kumar';
                //data += '&[2].Name=CustomerID&[2].Value=' + 'Ajit';
                //data += '&[3].Name=Status&[3].Value=' + 'Arun';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '*********/AjaxService.svc/DoWork',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: text,
                    success: function (text) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#Panel').show();
                        $('#Panel').html(text.d);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); }
                });
            });
        });
```

My Service Code

```
[OperationContract]
        //[WebInvoke (Method="POST")]
           [WebGet]
        public string DoWork(string text)
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            //return Get.Select(o => new ClientIssueEntry { FormName=o,Description=o+1});
            return text;
        }
```

Pls help me with this..

Comment: if we send param as query string its works fine..

Comment: var text = JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: the text not passing to service object (string text)thats the problem

Comment: try adding contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Answer (score 0):

Match name (`data`) of json variable with C# method parameter name; So either change `data` to `text` at JS end or `text` to `data` at C# end

Comment: Now i have big confusion that can we pass params to WCF service as data means is there anyway to pass param except as querystring.

Comment: you need to rename C# method param name to `data` something like `public string DoWork(string data){...}` if you pass JSON param with name `data`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SendSms").click(function () {
                var data = 'Muthu';
                var text = JSON.stringify({ text: data });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '*********/AjaxService.svc/DoWork',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: text,
                    success: function (text) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#Panel').show();
                        $('#Panel').html(text.d);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); }
                });
            });
        });

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public string DoWork(string text)
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            //return Get.Select(o => new ClientIssueEntry { FormName=o,Description=o+1});
            return text;
        }
```

Comment: s i changed but still  public string DoWork(string text) the text value always null only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing a GET operation, that also with just one or two non-complex parameters, I would suggest to use **UriTemplate**. Here is a sample based on your code:-

**The Interface:-**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAjaxService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "DoWork?text={text}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public string DoWork(string text);
}
```

**The Implementation**

```
AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class IAjaxService : AjaxService
    {
        public string DoWork(string text)
        {
            // Do your work here.....
            return text;
        }
    }
```

And call this from your javascript like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SendSms").click(function () {
                var input = 'Muthu';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "*********/AjaxService.svc/DoWork?text="+input,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (responseData) {
                        //Do your work here ....
                    },
                    error: function (err1, err2, err3) { alert(err3); }
                });
            });
        });
```

This will definitely work for you. In case you need some help, please post.